# Zoom in Canvas Tap Event winrt c#

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-runtime, click, zooming

I'm trying to zoom in a Canvas when I click on an element. 
This is my XAML code :

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MapCanvas" Width="{Binding ElementName=This, ath=ActualWidth}"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ElementName=Row1, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="CompositeTransform" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"></CompositeTransform>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40" Tap="UIElement_OnTap" Canvas.Left="417" Canvas.Top="186"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="40" Height="40" Tap="UIElement_OnTap"  Canvas.Left="333" Canvas.Top="135"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="40" Height="40" Tap="UIElement_OnTap"  Canvas.Left="333" Canvas.Top="223"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="40" Height="40" Tap="UIElement_OnTap"  Canvas.Left="498" Canvas.Top="135"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Width="40" Height="40" Tap="UIElement_OnTap"  Canvas.Left="498" Canvas.Top="223"/>
        </Canvas>
```

And this is My C# code when the Tap Method is fired :

```
 var mpos = e.GetPosition(MapCanvas);
        var parentcenter = new Point(((FrameworkElement)MapCanvas.Parent).ActualWidth / 2, ((FrameworkElement)MapCanvas.Parent).ActualHeight / 2);

        var sb1 = new Storyboard {Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800)};

        var scaleX = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800), To = parentcenter.X - mpos.X };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleX, MapCanvas);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleX, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"));
        sb1.Children.Add(scaleX);

        var scaleY = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800), To = parentcenter.Y - mpos.Y };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleY, MapCanvas);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleY, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"));
        sb1.Children.Add(scaleY);

        var centerX = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800), To = 5 };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(centerX, MapCanvas);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(centerX, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));
        sb1.Children.Add(centerX);

        var centerY = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800), To = 5 };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(centerY, MapCanvas);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(centerY, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"));
        sb1.Children.Add(centerY);
        sb1.Begin();
```

It's just a Storyboard which use Scale and Translate Transformation.
But the result is not satisfactory. The clicked element is not a the center.

How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Your `scaleX` and `scaleY` animations are being applied to the `TranslateX` and `TranslateY` properties.

Comment: Hmm yeah sorry it's just a mistake. I edit my code

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on how you want to zoom? Do you want to also be able to pan or just zoom in on the tapped element? Do you want to zoom just a bit on each tap, zoom to max scale that doesn't involve clipping or zoom to fill?

Comment: Note that this binding will not work: `Width="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=ActualWidth}"`. IIRC - `ActualWidth/Height` doesn't work as a binding source unless something changed recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is with

- rW is width of the rectangle
- rH is height of the rectangle
- rL is the Canvas.Left of the rectangle
- rT is the Canvas.Top of the rectangle
- cW is the canvas width
- cH is the canvas height

First, Scale (S) is determined by the smaller of cW/rW and cH/rH to fit on screen, or larger to fill it.

Then you want the center of the rectangle to be in the center of the canvas after scaling+translating the canvas, so assuming the `RenderTransformOrigin` of the Canvas is set to 0,0 for simplicity, after scaling without translation - the center of the rectangle would be in

- (rL + rW/2)*S,
- (rT + rH/2)*S

while you want it at

- cW/2,
- cH/2

so you need to translate by

- tX = cW/2 - (rL + rW/2)*S
- tY = cH/2 - (rT + rH/2)*S

These (S, tX, tY) are your `To` values for `ScaleX, ScaleY, TranslateX, TranslateY`.

Verified in Blend for

- rW:500
- rH:250
- rL:300
- rT:200
- cW:1366
- cH:768
- S:2.732
- tX:cW/2 - (rL + rW/2)*S = 683 - 550*2.732 = -819.6
- tY:cH/2 - (rT + rH/2)*S = 384 - 325*2.732 = -503.9

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App40.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App40"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="2.732"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="2.732"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-819.6"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-503.9"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid
    >
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry
        Rect="0,0,1366,768"/>
    </Grid.Clip>

        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Height="768" Width="1366">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="200"/>

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I'll push a custom Control on Github in a few hours. Maybe that could be help others people